# For over 4 hours it says payment has not been transmitted yet

Tags: wallet-recovery

Been getting message for over 4 hours that says "This payment has not been transmitted yet. Wallet version 7.47. What do I do?

Comment: you could start by telling us what wallet software you are using? there are many different bitcoin wallets, we don't have access to your wallet and can't read your mind.

Comment: Probably "Exodus" wallet based on a google search.